# restricting a combobox to list values and outdated list values

Tags: vb.net, validation, combobox

I am creating a program that for simplicity's sake records the name of a staff member that receives a phone call. This program is designed to show old entries along with creating new ones.

The problem is that I want a user to only be able to select a listed name from the drop box when creating a new entry. But this list will only show current employees. Yet, when viewing older calls this combobox field also needs to display former employees that took a call that may no longer be in this list.

As far as I can tell with the Microsoft control and properties there is only 2 options that relate to this matter.
*DropDownStyle* as *DropDown* or *DropDownList*.

When using *DropDown* the user can submit any name (which is not wanted).
With *DropDownList* the user can only submit names on the list, but when browsing through old entries any names that are no longer on that list will not appear on their respective calls (which is also not wanted).

I'm aware I could end up having to implement my own combobox class but I wanted to see if anyone knew of a more elegant fix that combined both of these functionalities. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure I understand your question... but if I do, you could add code to the `Validate` event to ensure the vlue you get is "allowed"

Comment: I would not use the same control to **display current and previous employees** and **display only current employees**. I would use a `ListBox` for previous calls and a `ComboBox` for current employees.

Comment: current and former employees are 2 different concepts, so dont try to commingle them

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you have two modes.  Add mode adds a new call record, while view mode displays old records.

Use the drop down list to restrict the user to what you load.  When in Add mode, load the control with only current employees.  When the form is in view mode, load with all employees.

Answer (score -1):

Use DropDown. In the Validating event, set `e.Cancel = True` and instruct an `ErrorProvider` control to put up a warning with its `SetError` method if `SelectedItem Is Nothing`, but clear the error (by passing `Nothing` to `SetError`) otherwise. Then, in the combo box's `SelectionChangeCommitted` event, call the form's `Validate` method.